# Dynamic SOQL in Map with unknow sobject?

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, dynamic-soql

is it possible to do SOQL for the unknown object without for loop as below

`string theQuery = 'Select '+fiels+' From'+obj_frm +whr;
Map <Id, object> oppMap = new Map<Id, object>((List<object>)Database.query(theQuery));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `SObject` as the value, not `Object`.

```
Map<Id, SObject> opportunities = new Map<Id, SObject>(Database.query(...));
```